# Excel VBA Copy Filtered and Paste to another TAB

Tags: excel, vba

Hi  Using Excel VBA putting some pieces together feel like this can use some ideas :-)

I am Filtering a column for not empty. Copying and Pasting to a reference tab. Deleting the filtered rows.
Thanks
Michelle

```
<Code>
    Sub Removed_Turned_In()
         Application.CutCopyMode = False                 '// clear clipboard
         Application.CutCopyMode = True                   '// reenable clipboard
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True               '// Shows action on screen

        Dim mainWS As Worksheet, refWS As Worksheet     '// sets worksheets and range
        Dim rng As Range, visRng As Range
        Set mainWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current")       '// sets to Current main TAB in this workbook
        Set refWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference")       '// sets copy to Reference TAB in the workbook

        If mainWS.FilterMode = True Then                   '// Remove the any existing filters from Current
            mainWS.ShowAllData
        End If
        If refWS.FilterMode = True Then                    '// Remove the any existing filters from Reference
            refWS.ShowAllData
        End If

      With mainWS

                                                        '// Filter Main Worksheet by Column 6 with NOT blank ie <>
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

        Set visRng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1)                           '// set visable Range
        visRng.Resize(visRng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy  '// copy visable Range minus header row

       refWS.Rows("2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow  
                               '// inserts copied cells into Reference Worksheet starting at Row 2

        visRng.Resize(visRng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete  
                       '// deletes copied cells from Current Worksheet

     End With

     Application.CutCopyMode = False                   '// clear clipboard
     Application.CutCopyMode = True                   '// reenable clipboard

        If mainWS.FilterMode = True Then          '// Remove the any existing filters from Current
             mainWS.ShowAllData
        End If
        If refWS.FilterMode = True Then           '// Remove the any existing filters from Reference
        refWS.ShowAllData
        End If

     End Sub
</code>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a condensed version of your code with all the excess removed, using Excel 2016. I do advocate using variables when they are used multiple times within a macro, but for a simple macro I find that too many variables can be confusing. Comments are contained in the macro. Since you didn't say there was a problem I think your question would probably have been better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

```
Sub FilterCopyInsertIntoRangeDelete()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'Note; If there are blank rows or columns within your data range, CurrentRegion will not select all the data

        .AutoFilter 'Reset if sheet is already filtered

        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Hide rows with no value in column

        'Copy the filtered(visible) data and insert between rows 1 and 2
        'Use resize/offset to adjust for your header row, copy visible row below the header.
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reference").Range("A2")
        'Or .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reference").Range("A2")

        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete 'Delete filtered data from source sheet

        .AutoFilter 'Remove filter

        'Note; "Application.CutCopyMode = False" is not required after you delete the range
    End With
End Sub
```